# Finding no. of time a value occurs with other combination

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column containing departments and another column containing Appt, Can, No show. I want to calculate how many time every department has occurred for Appt, Can and No Show. The code I am currently using extracts unique values of department and using If statements counts the value of Appt, Can and No Show.

Data Set:
http://bit.ly/1HkvAxR
    Code to get unique departments:

```
Public Sub Getting_Unique_Departments()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
If Len("E") > 0 And Len("Y") > 0 Then
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
X = Application.Transpose(Range("E" & 2, Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)))
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next
Range("Y" & 2 & ":" & "Y" & objDict.Count + 1) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End If

End Sub
```

Code to check Appt, Can, walk and No Show for each department.

```
Sub Calculation()
nName0 = "Department"
nName1 = "Appt"
nName2 = "Walk"
nName3 = "Can"
nName4 = "No Show"


Cells(1, 25).Value = nName0
Cells(1, 26).Value = nName1
Cells(1, 27).Value = nName2
Cells(1, 28).Value = nName3
Cells(1, 29).Value = nName4
For Dept_Row_number = 2 To Dept_lastRow

 'Dept_lastRow finds last Row of unique department listed in Y col and Sheet_lastRow finds the last Row of input data sheet.
nCount1 = 0
nCount1 = 0
nCount2 = 0
nCount3 = 0
nCount4 = 0

Row_number = 1

search_string1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Dept_Row_number, 25)


Do
DoEvents

Row_number = Row_number + 1

item_in_review1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row_number, 5).Value
item_in_review2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row_number, 3).Value



If InStr(item_in_review1, search_string1) > 0 And InStr(item_in_review2, "Appt") > 0 Then
        nCount1 = nCount1 + 1


ElseIf InStr(item_in_review1, search_string1) > 0 And InStr(item_in_review2, "Walk") > 0 Then
        nCount2 = nCount2 + 1

ElseIf InStr(item_in_review1, search_string1) > 0 And InStr(item_in_review2, "Can") > 0 Then
        nCount3 = nCount3 + 1

ElseIf InStr(item_in_review1, search_string1) > 0 And InStr(item_in_review2, "No Show") > 0 Then
        nCount4 = nCount4 + 1
End If

Loop Until Row_number = Sheet_lastRow



Cells(Dept_Row_number, 26).Value = nCount1
Cells(Dept_Row_number, 27).Value = nCount2
Cells(Dept_Row_number, 28).Value = nCount3
Cells(Dept_Row_number, 29).Value = nCount4
Next
```

Is there any easy way to this because in case I have to do this for more than one column, the code would be too cucumbersome.

Comment: Have you tried a Pivot Table?  That is the standard way to aggregate data for unique values.  You can use VBA to create the Pivot Table if needed.

Comment: I have worked with Pivot Table but due to some reason I have to do it by VBA only.

Comment: `do it by VBA only`... within VBA what are you allowed and not allowed to do?  You can create the Pivot Table in VBA, get all your summary numbers, report them somewhere, and delete the Pivot Table.

Answer (score 2):

Byron Wall is correct that Pivot Tables are a natural choice -- but you can also streamline the VBA. You are aware of dictionaries but could be exploiting them more. I recommend using early binding -- in Tools/References add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* and then you can write code along the following lines. The main loop populates a dictionary keyed to departments. The values of this dictionary are themselves dictionaries keyed by your categories ("No Show", etc.). The values of *those* dictionaries are the counts that you are after. At the end of the code I show how you can extract data from this data structure:

```
Function MakeCountDict(categories As Variant) As Dictionary
    Dim d As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(categories) To UBound(categories)
        d.Add categories(i), 0
    Next i
    Set MakeCountDict = d
End Function

Sub MakeDepartmentCounts()
    Dim Dcounts As New Dictionary
    Dim R As Range
    Dim dept As Variant, cat As String
    Dim categories As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim report As String

    categories = Array("No Show", "Appt", "Can", "walk")

    n = Range("H:H").Rows.Count
    n = Range("H" & n).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column H
    For i = 2 To n
        dept = Trim(Cells(i, "H").Value)
        If Not Dcounts.Exists(dept) Then
            Dcounts.Add dept, MakeCountDict(categories)
        End If
        cat = Trim(Cells(i, "C").Value)
        Dcounts(dept)(cat) = Dcounts(dept)(cat) + 1
    Next i

    report = "Report:"

    For Each dept In Dcounts.Keys
        report = report & vbCrLf & dept & ": "
        For i = 0 To 3
            cat = categories(i)
            report = report & cat & " = " & Dcounts(dept)(cat) & IIf(i < 3, ", ", "")
        Next i
    Next dept

    MsgBox report
End Sub
```

To test it I created random data in columns C and H that had the format of your linked picture then ran it. My output:

```
Department 5: No Show = 1, Appt = 1, Can = 1, walk = 2
Department 3: No Show = 5, Appt = 2, Can = 1, walk = 2
Department 4: No Show = 2, Appt = 1, Can = 0, walk = 1
Department 2: No Show = 2, Appt = 1, Can = 2, walk = 1
Department 1: No Show = 1, Appt = 1, Can = 0, walk = 2
```

This shows that the order of keys when you iterate is a bit random -- but you could do something like have a for j = 1 to 5 loop rather than a for each dept in keys loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The output is fine but I want it to be in some other sheet in the format as: http://bit.ly/1L4Ygx6. And due to some condition, I have to do it by VBA, and not by Pivot Table. Can you help?

Comment: What's up with "walk" vs. "Walk"? Your code might need to make sure that the keys are in a predictable case (say by running it through LCase()). The case of the final output can be however you want. In the code I gave I loaded the counts into a string. You could use the same loop structure to load it into a variant array (if V is declared variant then something like `Redim V(1 to 1+ Dcounts.Count,1 to 5)` to make room for headers -- load up this array using the data, declare a range variable, say rRange, set it  where you want it to go -- assign V to rRange.Value, then sort it in place.